# Stale associations in active record callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have Users who each have_one Profiles:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end
```

And each Profile belongs_to a User.  Profile also has a callback that reference's user.profile:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  after_create do
    puts user.profile.name
  end
end
```

And finally, say I've got some misc rails code like this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    user = User.create!
    user.profile
    user.create_profile!(name: 'kevin')
  end
end
```

This `foo` function will throw an exception (`undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`) in the `after_create` hook because `user.profile` is nil in profile.

The issue seems to occur when:
1. You create an object A
2. You reference A's association to B (which is nil)
3. You create B, associated to A
4. You have an after_create hook on B

In that circumstance, A's reference to B is stale, so A.B.A is nil.  `.reload` resolves it, of course: `A.reload.B.A` or `A.B.reload.A` works.

It happens for any AR hook I've tried (eg `after_save` or `after_commit`)

So - is there any good way around this?  Or do I have to scatter `.reload`s everywhere in my code (or the much more heavy-handed `clear_association_cache`)?

(And before anyone suggests is, no - I can't just replace `user.profile.name` with `self.name`.  It'd work in this stripped-down example, but my real-world use-cases are more complicated).